# Is resetting box-sizing to border-box relevant when using flexbox?

Tags: css, frontend, flexbox

I'm an Interaction Designer who occasionally dabbles in a bit of frontend experimentation, but I'm most definitely not a dev so apologies is this question isn't well phrased or relevant. I have recently been enjoying resetting the box-sizing as per the suggestion in [this article](https://css-tricks.com/inheriting-box-sizing-probably-slightly-better-best-practice/) but also was going to start playing with the flexbox property. As I've read that flexbox is a completely different take on the box model I was wondering if it made the notion of resetting box-sizing irrelevant or a bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really...the two aren't really related.

`flexbox` still uses values and you want those values to mean what they say.

You might hav a div with a `max/min width` which has `padding` and you want that value to be right.

`flexbox` doesn't mean that `box-sizing` is automatic or not a factor.

[**From the Spec**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#box-model)

> For all other values, flex-basis is resolved the same way as width in horizontal writing modes [CSS21]: percentage values of flex-basis are resolved against the flex item’s containing block, i.e. its flex container, and if that containing block’s size is indefinite, the result is the same as a main size of auto. Similarly, flex-basis determines the size of the content box, unless otherwise specified such as by box-sizing

See:

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.content {
  background: red;
  height: 75px;
  flex: 0 0 150px; /* max-width 150px */
  padding: 0 25px;
}
.boxy .content {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap boxy">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: okay great thanks :) for some reason I thought that if it was a new way of using the box model it might also have accommodated a way of making default box-sizing less weird!

Comment: so do they conflict in anyway? i.e. will box-sizing cause problems with flexbox? that seems to be what the last sentence from the spec suggests

Comment: I've not had any conflicts but I don't think so. Might be worth a Google.